# Can I use The mpu6050 with this?

Tags: communication, mpu6050

I am making a project with 3 arduinos (2 slave, 1 master) and I want to know can I use the mpu6050 since it uses the I2c communication.

Comment: You're using I2C for the Arduino->Arduino communication?

Comment: yes i am using  it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only from the master. You have one I2C bus with three slave devices on it - two arduinos and one mpu6050.

Comment: thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can but keep the I2C wires less then about 30cm. If they are going to be further apart consider something like RS485 or CAN. Are you sure you need three?

Comment: Yes i do I am making a car/ drone combo https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=smart+ideas+consept+drone&pbjreload=102